# Implementing a frontend for a c++ console application using QProcess

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I am trying to implement GUI for a simple C++ using Qt to understand how it works. The C++ program and the GUI are in seperate projects in the same solution in VS 2015. The Qt program will call the C++ program using QProcess' start() function. The C++ console application will be running the background will the Qt program acts as an interface. My question is, how I do I pass values to the C++ program using QProcess and How do I obtain the output from the C++ program? Here is the sample program I am working with:-

The C++ Program

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

void main() {
    int a;
    cout << "Enter a number" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "The Square of the number is " << (a*a) << endl;
        ofstream write;
        write.open("test.txt");
        write << (a * a);
        write.close();
}
```

The Qt Program

```
#include "FrontEnd.h" 
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <qprocess.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    FrontEnd w;
    w.show();

    QProcess p1;
    p1.start("Interface.exe");
    p1.write("5",5);
    return a.exec();
}
```

I tried to pass the value using the write() function but it did not seem to work as the test.txt file remained empty. The Qt program I have written lacks the GUI features as I will be adding them once I figure out how to send and recieve data using QProcess. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: It's simple! Once the process started (wait for its `started()` signal or `QProcess::waitForStarted()`), write to its `stdin` by `write` method of the process. Then the C++ process gets the data by its `cin` command and returns the result (for simplicity don't write the result on file, return it on `stdout` instead), so in the Qt app you can read the `stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

You have many problems in the code you are showing:

1. You are passing [`write`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write) two arguments `"5"` and `5`, this means that it will use 5 `char`s from the the `char*` `"5"`. Absolutely, this is not what you want as this will lead to undefined behavior resulted from accessing memory that does not belong to your data.

   Instead you should be using the [second version of `write`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write-1) which accepts a zero-terminated string, like this: `p1.write("5");`
2. In order to make `cin` in your console program *know* that the number it should read is finished, you should pass a new line after your number, so your call will end up like this: `p1.write("5\n");`
3. You should use the [`readyRead`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readyRead) signal in the Qt program to *get notified* when your process has new output that you can read, and then you may call [`readAll`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readAll) from a slot which is connected to that signal.

For completeness, Here is how your code should be:

#### interface.cpp

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void main() {
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    //No need to use file output
    //it is simpler and more appropriate to read the output from stdout
    cout << "The Square of the number is " << (a*a) << endl;
}
```

#### The Qt program

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>
#include "FrontEnd.h" 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    FrontEnd w;
    w.show();

    QProcess p1;
    p1.start("Interface.exe");
    p1.write("5\n");
    QObject::connect(&p1, &QProcess::readyRead, [&p1](){
        //output to qDebug, you may want to update some GUI component instead
        qDebug() << p1.readAll();
    });
    return a.exec();
}
```